# pandas running extremely slow

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to read in a tsv file (0.5gb) using pandas however, I can't seem to get it to work. I have stripped my code down to its simplest form and still no luck:

```
import pandas as pd
import os


rawpath = 'my path'
filename = 'my file name'
finalfile = os.path.join(rawpath, filename)

df = pd.read_csv(finalfile, nrows=5000, sep='\t')
print(df.head())
```

I have tried to chunk the file, with no luck, read_table doesn't work either. I have gone in and freed up as much memory as possible on my machine but when I finally recieve any output from Pycharm, it says:

pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: out of memory

Can anyone assist please?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting dtype=object and na_values = "Your NA format" (optional, if you know it)

Also, make sure you have the right separator.

something like:

```py
df = pd.read_csv(finalfile, nrows=5000, sep='\t', dtype=object, na_values = '-NaN')
```

Edit:
Also, you mentioned chunking the file. I am not sure what you mean by that, but i will mention that you can chunk directly using pandas, instead of nrows. Final code:

```
mylist = []

for chunk in  pd.read_csv(finalfile, sep='\t', dtype=object, na_values = '-NaN', chunksize=100):
    mylist.append(chunk)

big_data = pd.concat(mylist, axis= 0)
del mylist
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the response, neither option has solved the problem i'm afraid. Would a disk cleanup help?

Comment: It is more RAM related. Try to see if you have enough available RAM. Close unneeded apps, other running processes, try restarting Pycharm

Comment: Open Task Manager (on Windows) to see how much RAM you have unused

Comment: Currently have 4gb available of 8gb

Comment: I'm using pycharm, could that be the cause?

Comment: Possible. Try using another IDE and see if the error persists.